# Testing bitflip code in DDR no longer working with GCC-4.7.0

Tags: c, gcc, bootloader

Had a code which was used to test out DDR and it used to work fine with GCC-4.2.4 but after we moved to GCC-4.7.0 bit flips are observed after the below code is executed ; is this due to a bug in the code or I need to handle something for the new compiler ; given below is the code snippet :

```
int test_bitflip_comparison(unsigned long volatile *bufa, unsigned long volatile *bufb, size_t count) {
unsigned long volatile *p1 = bufa;
unsigned long volatile *p2 = bufb;
unsigned int j, k;
unsigned long q;
size_t i;
char *msgBuf;

for (k = 0; k < UL_LEN; k++) {
    q = ONE << k;
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
         q = ~q;
        p1 = (unsigned long volatile *) bufa;
        p2 = (unsigned long volatile *) bufb;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            *p1++ = *p2++ = (i % 2) == 0 ? q : ~q;
        }
        if (compare_regions(bufa, bufb, count)) {
    return -1;
        }
    }
if(!(k % 10))
    puts1(".\0");
}
return 0;
```

}

```
int compare_regions(unsigned long volatile *bufa, unsigned long volatile *bufb, size_t count) {
int r = 0;
size_t i;
unsigned long physaddr;
unsigned long volatile *p1 = bufa;
unsigned long volatile *p2 = bufb;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++, p1++, p2++) {
    if (*p1 != *p2) {
        if (use_phys) {
            physaddr = physaddrbase + (i * sizeof(unsigned long));
        } else {
        }
          r = -1;
    }
}
return r;
```

}

Comment: Is this actual code? 'cos your bracing is all out for your else case r = -1

Comment: How is `ONE` defined, and how `UL_LEN`?

Comment: #define ONE 0x00000001L ; #define UL_LEN 32 ; this is a snippet from my original code

Comment: When `long` is a 32-bit type, you're running into undefined behaviour with that. `#define ONE 1ul` to avoid that. and `#define UL_LEN (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long))` to get the proper bound even when the size changes. [If `unsigned long` has padding bits, that would invoke UB too, but I've not yet heard of an actual implementation that has padding bits in `unsigned long`.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give me some insight into how long can cause undefined behavior ?

Comment: `1L << 31` overflows if `long` is a 32-bit type. Overflow of signed integers is undefined behaviour. Making the shifted quantity an `unsigned long` avoids that (then the shift only invokes undefined behaviour if the shift distance is larger than or equal to the width of the type, which is `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long) - padding_bits`; though it is not guaranteed that there are no padding bits, for the standard unsigned types, it's a tolerable risk).

Comment: I enabled Wstrict-overflow ; Gcc was not showing me any warnings ; Why is that this is not getting caught by GCC ? Is there any option in GCC I can enable to catch such serious issues ?

Comment: The compiler will warn when the shift count is constant, but in your case it is a variable.